# TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "tuple") to str How do i fix this?

Tags: python, string, tuples, concatenation, new-operator

So i am a fairly new python user and i'm trying to make a game of rock paper scissors where you can either play against the AI or a simulation vs 2 real people (local gamee) but i keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "tuple") to str
```

Here's the line(s) of code where the problem occured:

```
print("Hello" + User1 + "and" + User2 +  "please enter 2 again")

print(User1 + " played " + x)

print(User2 + " played " + y)
```

Here is a link to the entire code:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKzVA.png
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Why User1 and User2 are tuples ?

Comment: `User1` and `User2` are zero-length tuples.  What did you expect it to print there?  Perhaps you should initialize them as `User1 = "user 1"` and `User2 = "user 2"` until you figure out how to input names there.

Comment: Your error seems to be that you set `User1` and `User2` to be empty tuples instead of strings due to a misunderstanding of how `format` works.  What you want to do is something more like `User1, User2 = map(str.strip, input("enter User1, User2").split(","))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've initialized your user names as empty tuples here:

```
User1 = ()
User2 = ()
```

In your print statement, you attempt to concatenate a string with that tuple:

```
print("Hello" + User1 + "and" + User2 +  "please enter 2 again")
```

Python does not define an addition between a tuple and a string, so it throws a Type Error. I'd recommend defining your user names as empty strings until you decide how to handle their entry into your program.